# ClickHouse Materialized View generating too slow

Tags: performance, aggregate, query-optimization, clickhouse, materialized-views

We collect raw events into a ClickHouse table. Table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS raw_events
(
    owner_id                  UInt32,
    user_id                   UInt32,
    event_datetime            DateTime,
    event_type_id             UInt8,
    unique_id                 FixedString(18),
    data                      String,
    attr_1                    UInt32,
    attr_2                    UInt32
)
    engine = MergeTree PARTITION BY toYYYYMMDD(event_datetime)
    ORDER BY (owner_id, user_id, event_type_id, event_datetime);
```

At the moment *raw_events* table contains **120000000 (120M) rows**.

We aim to show our users some aggregate statistics for those events, thus we created a materialized view:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW test
ENGINE = AggregatingMergeTree() PARTITION BY (date)
ORDER BY (owner_id, user_id, date)
AS SELECT
       toYYYYMMDD(event_datetime) as date,
       owner_id,
       user_id,
       multiIf(
                   event_type_id == 1, 10,
                   event_type_id == 2, 20,
                   event_type_id == 3, 30,
                   event_type_id == 4, 40,
                   event_type_id == 32, 50,
                   event_type_id >= 64, 60,
                   0
           ) as status,
       attr_1,
       attr_2,
       COUNT() as count,
       COUNT(DISTINCT unique_id) as unique_count
   FROM raw_events
   GROUP BY owner_id, user_id, date, status, attr_1, attr_2
   ORDER BY owner_id, user_id, date;
```

If we run the select query separately, it takes around 1 second to generate a response for a single owner_id. But creating a materialized view for the same select takes too much time. After executing *create materialized view* query it generated just **200 records** and it took it **~10 minutes**. So it looks like it will take days to completely build a view for the current 120M records table.

What am I missing? Maybe there are some tricks for order/group clauses to make it run faster? At the moment it's much easier for me to just run select+group query instead of using a materialized view.

Additional question: is there a way to check the progress for materialized view building for an existing table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. AggregatingMergeTree -- uses `ORDER BY`  as collapsing rule.
2. AggregatingMergeTree -- have to be used with AggregateFunctions + -State + -Merge combinators
3. ORDER BY -- is excessive

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW test
ENGINE = AggregatingMergeTree() PARTITION BY (date)
ORDER BY (owner_id, user_id, date, status, attr_1, attr_2)         ---<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<-----------
AS SELECT
       toYYYYMMDD(event_datetime) as date,
       owner_id,
       user_id,
       multiIf(
                   event_type_id == 1, 10,
                   event_type_id == 2, 20,
                   event_type_id == 3, 30,
                   event_type_id == 4, 40,
                   event_type_id == 32, 50,
                   event_type_id >= 64, 60,
                   0
           ) as status,
       attr_1,
       attr_2,
       countState() as count,                                  ---<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<-----------
       uniqState(unique_id) as unique_count        ---<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<-----------
   FROM raw_events
   GROUP BY owner_id, user_id, date, status, attr_1, attr_2
```

https://gist.github.com/den-crane/a72614fbe6d23eb9c2f1bce40c66893f

https://gist.github.com/den-crane/49ce2ae3a688651b9c2dd85ee592cb15

https://den-crane.github.io/Everything_you_should_know_about_materialized_views_commented.pdf

Comment: Perfect, thank you a lot! The pdf file you provided has so much useful info I couldn't find before. But I still have a question regarding the unique_count. It counts distinct unique_ids within the row (group) which is expected. But Idially I need to count unique ids just once, regardless of the date. So, if I have identical combinations of all params happening twice (on 29.01.2000 and 30.01.2000), I want only count a unique occurance on 29.01.2020 (the first one chronologically) and ignore it for 30.01.2020. Is that even possible? Or would you rather suggest using different approach for this?

Comment: Just to give you some context. Same event happens twice on different days. By "same event" I mean a unique combination of owner+user+status+attr1+attr2+uniqueid. We want to show statistics for user, devided by days. And on that statistics we want count the event only the first time it occurred. But for me it looks impossible, because we already grouping everything by day, and aggregation functions use within that groups. Any suggestions? I'm stuck with this question for days now.

Comment: uniqState -- CH stores states (not a number of uniqs). Everything will work as you expected with states. https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/aggregate-functions/reference/uniqhll12/ Try a simple example, with two columns and 10 rows.

Comment: Hey again. Almost everything is running now, thanks again. The only thing that still not working properly is the count of uniqs. I created MV which groups my events per hour, and I save state of the uniq events as uniqState(unique_id, status). But if the same event happens twice (at 8 and 9 o'clock), uniqMerge() shows "1" for both 8 and 9 hour rows. I can work with it, but ideally, I need it count uniqs MV-wide, so that it would return "1" for 8 hour row, and "0" for 9 hour row. Is that even possible? I feel like I can achieve it somehow with aggregate function modifiers, but I see no solution

Comment: `uniqState(unique_id, status)` -- this is incorrect. Make an example with `create table` / `create MV ` / `insert sample rows` / `query actual result` / `desired result`

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo, it should be just uniqState(unique_id). Anyway, here you go: https://gist.github.com/Hast/f2f11cdd8011ee51ed9d1d608eb0d149 All the queries and expected/actual results. I'm not even sure it's possible, because for example in MySQL it requires to make complex subqueries to achieve this. But on the other hand clickhouse smartly merges uniques when I group everything by day (example included in the gist), so I have hope that it's still possible. Anyway, I'm good with the current results, but it would be perfect if I can ignore states that already exists in previous rows.

Comment: I asked this as a separate question, so other people could find the answer if it exists: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68914002/clickhouse-count-unique-combinations-only-for-first-row-in-grouped-query I guess this is not a very rare question, but it's impossible to find and answer for it google.