# ClickHouse count unique combinations only for first row in grouped query

Tags: count, aggregate, unique, clickhouse, materialized-views

This question is a extension for my previous [question about MVs performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68656704/clickhouse-materialized-view-generating-too-slow)

Problem: when counting unique combinations of my source table, I want only increment the counter for the first found row, not for each group. Details below:

Source table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS events
(
    user_id                   UInt32,
    event_datetime            DateTime,
    event_type_id             UInt8,
    message_id                FixedString(2)
)
engine = MergeTree PARTITION BY toYYYYMMDD(event_datetime)
ORDER BY (user_id, event_type_id, event_datetime);
```

Hourly preaggregated MV:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW events_hourly
ENGINE = AggregatingMergeTree() PARTITION BY (toYYYYMMDD(event_day_hour))
ORDER BY (user_id, event_type_id, event_day_hour)
AS SELECT
          toStartOfHour(event_datetime) as event_day_hour,
          user_id,
          event_type_id,
          countState()               as count,
          uniqState(message_id) as unique_count
   FROM events
   GROUP BY user_id, event_type_id, event_day_hour;
```

Insert data:

```
INSERT INTO events (user_id, event_datetime, event_type_id, message_id)
VALUES
    (1, toDateTime('2021-01-01 08:00:00'), 1, 'a1')
    (1, toDateTime('2021-01-01 08:00:00'), 1, 'a2')
    (1, toDateTime('2021-01-01 08:00:00'), 1, 'a1')
    (1, toDateTime('2021-01-01 08:00:00'), 2, 'a1')
    (1, toDateTime('2021-01-01 08:00:00'), 2, 'a1')
    (1, toDateTime('2021-01-01 08:00:00'), 3, 'a1')
    (1, toDateTime('2021-01-01 08:00:00'), 4, 'a1')
    (1, toDateTime('2021-01-01 09:00:00'), 1, 'a1')
    (1, toDateTime('2021-01-01 09:00:00'), 1, 'a1')
    (1, toDateTime('2021-01-01 08:00:00'), 2, 'a1')
    (1, toDateTime('2021-01-01 08:00:00'), 3, 'a2')
    (1, toDateTime('2021-01-02 08:00:00'), 1, 'a1')
    (1, toDateTime('2021-01-01 08:00:00'), 1, 'a2')
;
```

Select HOURLY statistics from MV with final aggregation (all selects are always per user):

```
SELECT
    event_day_hour,
    multiIf(
        event_type_id == 1, 10,
        event_type_id == 2, 10,
        20
    ) as status,
countMerge(count),
uniqMerge(unique_count)
FROM events_hourly
WHERE user_id=1
GROUP BY status, event_day_hour
ORDER BY event_day_hour, status;
```

**Actual result (hourly):**

| Day and Hour | Status | Count | Unique count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 08:00:00 | 10 | 7 | 2 |
| 2021-01-01 08:00:00 | 20 | 3 | 2 |
| 2021-01-01 09:00:00 | 10 | 2 | 1 |
| 2021-01-02 08:00:00 | 10 | 1 | 1 |

**Expected result (hourly):**

| Day and Hour | Status | Count | Unique count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 08:00:00 | 10 | 7 | 2 |
| 2021-01-01 08:00:00 | 20 | 3 | 2 |
| 2021-01-01 09:00:00 | 10 | 2 | 0 |
| 2021-01-02 08:00:00 | 10 | 1 | 0 |

*(Unique count for row 3 and 4 should be 0, because unique combination with message a1 and status 10 already exists in row 1)*

Select DAILY statistics from MV with final aggregation (all selects are always per user):

```
SELECT
    toYYYYMMDD(event_day_hour) as day,
    multiIf(
        event_type_id == 1, 10,
        event_type_id == 2, 10,
        20
    ) as status,
    countMerge(count),
    uniqMerge(unique_count)
FROM events_hourly
WHERE user_id=1
GROUP BY status, day
ORDER BY day, status;
```

**Actual result (daily):**

| Day and Hour | Status | Count | Unique count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20210101 | 10 | 9 | 2 |
| 20210101 | 20 | 3 | 2 |
| 20210102 | 10 | 1 | 1 |

**Expected result (daily):**

| Day and Hour | Status | Count | Unique count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20210101 | 10 | 9 | 2 |
| 20210101 | 20 | 3 | 2 |
| 20210102 | 10 | 1 | 0 |

*(Unique count for row 3 should be 0, because unique combination with message a1 and status 10 already exists in row 1)*

Gist link for the convenience: https://gist.github.com/Hast/f2f11cdd8011ee51ed9d1d608eb0d149

Comment: It's impossible with AggregatingMergeTree & uniqStates. CH does not have `overlap` or `retention` function for HLL structures. It seems possible in theory.

Comment: You can try to use `retention` function against raw data.

Comment: Yup, that's what I thought. Thanks anyway!